# Is it possible to make this AHK script?

Tags: autohotkey

I attempted to made ahk key that,

(WHILE PRESSING FN
wait for next key to enter
then add that key to the beginning and
end of the already selected line)

```
FN::
    SendInput {LButton down}{Shift down}
    Sleep, 50
    SendInput {Shift up}{LButton up}
    StringRight, line, clipboard, 1
    Send, {Blind}{FN}
    key := "{A_ThisHotkey}"
    SendInput {Home}{Shift down}{End}{Shift up}
    SendInput {BS}
    SendInput {BS}
    SendInput {BS}
    SendInput {BS}
    SendInput {BS}
    SendInput {BS}
    SendInput {BS}
    SendInput %key%{line}%key%
return
```

Comment: I looked through KeyHistory and the ``FN`` key is not listed, see this: https://superuser.com/a/1531600/1555369

Comment: That's because it's not physically possible because the operating system doesn't even receive function keypresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key#:~:text=However%2C%20because%20the%20operating%20system%20has%20no%20notion%20of%20the%20Fn%20key%2C%20the%20key%20can%20not%20normally%20be%20remapped%20in%20software